# magento tax page is showing blank or nothing

Tags: magento

In Magento admin panel When I go to System > Configuration and then under sales when I click on Tax then it is showing blank page.

I want to change some settings in tax, So please tell me how Can I fix that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the Compiler Process is Admin panel to check the changes.